# Too Many Redirects - htaccess/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Seem to be getting a "too many redirects" error when trying to put all the 301s in place from the old site.  It seems to specifically be happening with any pages that were in subfolders (i.e. blog)

Trying to start by forcing non-www over https.  Then redirecting individual pages that had a url change.

htaccess looks like this currently:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Yoast SEO - XML Sitemap Rewrite Fix
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml [L]
RewriteRule ^geo_sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=geo [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 [L]
# END Yoast SEO - XML Sitemap Rewrite Fix

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks

# match any URL with www and rewrite it to https without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# match urls that are non https (without the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Original Site Redirects (From the previous website)

Redirect 301 /tell https://example.com/contact
Redirect 301 /blog https://example.com/blog
Redirect 301 /sitemap https://example.com/sitemap_index.xml
Redirect 301 /blog/asking-help https://example.com/asking-for-financial-help
Redirect 301 /blog/planning-special-needs https://example.com/financial-planning-for-special-needs
```

**What's working:**

- The non-www, https force works as intended.
- Contact, blog and the sitemap all redirect properly.

**What's NOT working:**

- From what I can tell, anything redirecting from the original blog folder is getting the "too many redirects" error - so blog/asking-help and blog/planning-special-needs in the example above.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Is it possible that your original site redirect rules are being thrown into an infinite loop based upon the other rules above it? What happens if you (in a test environment) comment out everything except the original site re-directs? Does that work as expected?

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy - Yeah.  I should've ruled that out first.  So yes, the non-www, https force is what was causing the loop.

Interestingly, with that taken out, the site still redirects properly to the non-www, https version.  I guess I can chalk it up to "yay, it's working", though I'd like to understand what's going on there.  There's gotta be another function within the theme I'm using that's already handled that redirect.

Comment: Always put your custom RewriteRule *before* the WP block, or WP will deal with the requests before your RewriteRules are checked.